# How to get items from a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have the following hash being returned from the Google Drive API:

```
@export_links=
 {"application/rtf"=>
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxx&exportFormat=rtf",
  "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"=>
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxx&exportFormat=odt",
  "text/html"=>
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxx&exportFormat=html",
  "application/pdf"=>
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxx&exportFormat=pdf",
  "application/zip"=>
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxx&exportFormat=zip",
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"=>
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxxx&exportFormat=docx",
  "text/plain"=>
   "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=xxx&exportFormat=txt"},
```

I'm able to log export links like so:

```
logger.debug  file.export_links
```

However, I'm unable to get the text/plain url, trying:

```
logger.debug  file.export_links["text/plain"]
```

This is erroring with `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass`.

How can I get the value for text/plain within @export_links?

Comment: What's `file.export_links.class`?

Comment: @spickermann that returns Hash or NilClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
@export_links.select { |k, v| v if k == 'text/plain' }
```

Or

```
@export_links.find { |k, _| k == 'text/plain' }
```

if you need the first match.

Comment: The 1st idea returns `private method `select' called for nil:NilClass` the 2nd `undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Your code example shows assignment to `@export_links`. It's supposed to contain the hash but was nil when you tried the idea.